# How to swap out WaitForSeconds for WaitForKeyPress

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am designing a scene where the first person character walks over to a note, picks it up, reads it for a few seconds, then puts it down. It is accomplished by the code below and works great.
However, a friend mentioned that it would be better to maybe have the note go away when pressing the e key again.

I have tried using WaitForInput(), WaitForKeyPress, and a few flavors of "if" statements but none have actually worked seamlessly like WaitForSeconds and after scrambling up my code so many times I decided to revert back to the time version until I can figure this out.

I'm hoping to end up with just the correct syntax and which method to actually use to wait for the keypress. Using the search bar in the Unity manual returns very little for WaitForKeyPress and WaitForInput so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ReadNote : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Image customImage;
    public float TheDistance;
    public GameObject ActionDisplay;
    public GameObject ActionText;
    public GameObject ExtraCross;
    public GameObject Note1;
    public GameObject ThePlayer;
    public GameObject TextBox;
    public AudioSource PageUp;
    public AudioSource PageDown;

    void Update()
    {
        TheDistance = PlayerCasting.DistanceFromTarget;
    }

    void OnMouseOver()
    {
        if (TheDistance <= 4)
        {
            ExtraCross.SetActive(true);
            ActionDisplay.SetActive(true);
            ActionText.SetActive(true);

        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Action"))
        {
            //stop player movement
            ThePlayer.GetComponent<FirstPersonController> ().enabled = false;
            StartCoroutine(ScenePlayer());



            if (TheDistance <= 4)
            {
                this.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = false;
                ActionDisplay.SetActive(false);
                ActionText.SetActive(false);
                customImage.enabled = true;
                PageUp.Play();
            }
        }

            IEnumerator ScenePlayer()
            {
                TextBox.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "3400.";
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
                TextBox.GetComponent<Text>().text = "";
                ThePlayer.GetComponent<FirstPersonController>().enabled = true;
                customImage.enabled = false;
                PageDown.Play();

        }
    }
    void OnMouseExit()
    {
        ExtraCross.SetActive(false);
        ActionDisplay.SetActive(false);
        ActionText.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WaitUntil()` this can wait for bool properties or fields to come true via `() =>` or you can pass it a method, or you can even wait for bool expressions to come true eg: `() => x > 5`

*Your coroutine changed to only continue execution when the keyboard button "e" is released:*

```
IEnumerator ScenePlayer()
{
    TextBox.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "3400.";
    // This will pause the coroutine execution till the keyboard button e is released
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.E));
    TextBox.GetComponent<Text>().text = "";
    ThePlayer.GetComponent<FirstPersonController>().enabled = true;
    customImage.enabled = false;
    PageDown.Play();
}
```